# Find the smallest subring of $\mathbb{Z}$ containing $8$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Find the smallest subring of $\mathbb{Z}$ containing $8$.
My attempt: I have formed a subring containing 8 i.e. $\{8n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}\cup\{8^k \mid k\in\mathbb{Z}, k>0\}$. But how do I know if it is the smallest?

Comment: If $R$ is a ring containing $8$, $R$ must contain $8$, $8+8$, $8+8+8$ and so on, and also $-8$, $-(8+8)$, $-(8+8+8)$ and so on, and $0$.

Comment: Shouldn't a subring contain $1$? (That is, $\Bbb Z$ has no proper subring).

Comment: Depends on your definition, I'm pretty sure Herstein for one defines rings without requiring an identity, and defines unital rings to be rings with an identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the second set after the cup symbol is already contained in the first set.

A slick way to see that the set you chose is the smallest subring containing 8 is to note that, additively, it is the smallest subgroup containing 8. Since a subring must be an additive subgroup and this subgroup happens to be a ring, it must be the smallest subring.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest *additive subgroup* of $\mathbb Z$ that contains $8$ is clearly $8\mathbb Z$, because it contains $8$ and is closed under addition and subtraction.

If you do not require that subrings contain $1$, then $8\mathbb Z$ is a subring, because it is also closed under multiplication, and so it's the smallest one.